# compare model in foreach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, linq-to-sql, foreach

Someone know how to compare a string to a item in a model in a foreach declaration?
example:
i have this foreach loop

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    //code here
}
```

But i want to only display items that equals another string like for example:

```
String example ="Hello"
@foreach (var item in Model.where(c => c.Name).equals() example)  
{
    //code here
}
```

???? this is not working for me and i dont know how to make it.

i want to know how can you compare a item in your model inside the foreach loop to a string

Comment: What's your model definition?

Comment: You have to write "Where" with an upper case "W" and "Equals" with an upper case "E". C# is case sensitive! Also you are closing the parentheses too early. It should be `Model.Where(c => c.Name.Equals(example))`. And also pass `example` as parameter to `Equals`.

Comment: yeha i know c# is case sensitive i write it in lower case just for showing porpuse i was refering that i didnt know how to make the "where" statement correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass a correct predicate to the `Where` extension method:

```
string example ="Hello"
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(c => c.Name == example))
{

}
```

To use the `Where` extension method, your model needs to implement `IEnumerable<T>` interface (it probably does if you use it in a `foreach`).

Also make sure that the `System.Linq` namespace is open your view. Otherwise you will not be able to access the extension methods defined there.

Answer (score 1):

**Provided that** you want all the objects that are contained in your model, whose `Name` property is equal to the value of `example`, you need the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(c => c.Name==example))  
{
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can just put the equality comparison in the `where` predicate like this:

```
String example ="Hello"
@foreach (var item in Model.where(c => c.Name=="example") example)  
               {
                //code here
               }
```